# Open all the images in a folder (SD card) at once on button click

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdcard, android-broadcast, android-mediascanner

**What I want:** clicking a button should open all the images which are in a specific folder on the SD card .

**What is happening:** if folder has more than one image then the app is showing a single image only .

**Button Click Method Code:**

```
private void showGallery() {

    if ((personName.getText().toString() != null && !personName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            && (mobileNo.getText() != null && !mobileNo.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    photoPath + personName.getText().toString() + "_" + mobileNo.getText().toString() + "/");

        File[] allFiles = folder.listFiles();
        if (allFiles != null && allFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File child : allfiles) {
                new SingleMediaScanner(getActivity(), child);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

**SingleMediaScanner Code:**

```
public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient {

        private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
        private File mFile;

        public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
            mFile = f;
            mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
            mMs.connect();
        }

        public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
            mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), "image/*");
        }

        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            mMs.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you want your images to be shown? in a listview?

Comment: @alexeypolusov : No , want t open that folder either inside gallery app or wanna open the folder .

Answer (score 0):

Use Swipable cards library (Tinder like). This will show the stack of all images.
Below link is helpful for you:
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/222

Comment: i don't want to use Library . Wanna resolve it by MediaScanner .